# How do I find/use eGit in the Android Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, egit

All the web resources say File->Team->Share, but I don't have any of that in my menu. I made sure it was installed, and even updated it. Still can't find it in any of the menus.

This is probably dirt simple for someone, so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Do you have the Git Repositories view? Can you import from Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I access the eGit context menu by right-clicking a project in the Package Explorer menu.  Try and see if you can see Team then.

Comment: That seems like it might do it. I'm going to see if I can get it working. Thanks

Comment: Well.. eGit couldn't move resources for some unexplained reason, but it seems to have spliced my project. And now all the team menu contains is "Apply Patch" which doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: That sounds like the project may not be tracked by git.  Is this the case?

Comment: I got it all working in the end, egit made a local repository but didn't seem to want to push it to git, so I went over it's head and used the git shell. Thanks pal.